# jQuery datetimepicker to dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetimepicker

with angular I clone my fields like this

```
$scope.edu_rows = [0];
var edu_counter = 0;

$scope.cloneEduRow = function () {
    edu_counter++;

    if ($scope.edu_rows.length === 10)
        alert('Entry limit reached!');
    else {
        $scope.edu_rows.push(edu_counter);
    }

};

$scope.removeEduRow = function (rowIndex) {
    $scope.edu_rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
};
```

through a ng-repeat

```
<div data-ng-repeat="row in edu_rows">
                        <div class="col-md-15 form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][school]"
                                       placeholder="School">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][teaching]"
                                       placeholder="Teaching">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][start_date]"
                                           placeholder="Start Date">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][end_date]"
                                           placeholder="End Date">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="btn btn-icon white col-sm-1 pull-right" data-ng-click="removeEduRow($index)">
                                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

in the bottom of my view I iniate datetimepicker

```
$(".date").datetimepicker({
        viewMode: 'years',
        format:   'MM/YYYY',
        icons:    {
            time:     'fa fa-clock-o',
            date:     'fa fa-calendar',
            up:       'fa fa-chevron-up',
            down:     'fa fa-chevron-down',
            previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
            next:     'fa fa-chevron-right',
            today:    'fa fa-screenshot',
            clear:    'fa fa-trash',
            close:    'fa fa-remove'
        }
    });
```

but this only works for the first row, added rows don't get the plugin, I tried using focus: `$(document).on("focus", ".date", function () {`

but that didnt work, putting it in my angular controller kinda works, it iniates it for the previous added row after pressing the button, but yet not for the currently added row.

Help appreciated.

Comment: you can create directive for datepicker in controller.js and used it.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: you can see this link may be it's help full http://www.encodedna.com/angularjs/tutorial/how-to-implement-jquery-ui-datepicker-in-angularjs.htm#comment-3257226035

Comment: and sure your datepicker it's open and working on go text box in ng-repeat??

Comment: no, thats the point, it doesnt open in the repeat

Comment: yes i know that i am give the answer you can try it and let me know it's work or not it's very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This working example will help you to resolve your issue.

```js
 var app = angular.module('app1', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ( $scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.edu_rows = [0];
        var edu_counter = 0;

        $scope.cloneEduRow = function () {
            edu_counter++;

            if ($scope.edu_rows.length === 10)
                alert('Entry limit reached!');
            else {
                $scope.edu_rows.push(edu_counter);
            }
            $scope.bindDataTimePicker();
        };

        $scope.removeEduRow = function (rowIndex) {
            $scope.edu_rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
        };

        $scope.bindDataTimePicker = function () {
            $timeout(function () {
                $(".date").datetimepicker({
                    viewMode: 'years',
                    format: 'MM/YYYY',
                    icons: {
                        time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
                        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
                        up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
                        down: 'fa fa-chevron-down',
                        previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
                        next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
                        today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
                        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
                        close: 'fa fa-remove'
                    }
                });
            }, 100);
        }
        $scope.bindDataTimePicker();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app1" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div data-ng-repeat="row in edu_rows">
        <div class="col-md-15 form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][school]"
                       placeholder="School">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][teaching]"
                       placeholder="Teaching">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][start_date]"
                           placeholder="Start Date">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="input-group date">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][end_date]"
                           placeholder="End Date">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="btn btn-icon white col-sm-1 pull-right" data-ng-click="removeEduRow($index)">
                <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="cloneEduRow()">Add New</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create directive in you xyz.js like this:

```
app.directive("date", function () {
function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    // CALL THE "datetimepicker()" METHOD USING THE "element" OBJECT.

    element.datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY', // here your need format is used i am just put here 
        icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
            down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
            previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
            next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
            today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
            clear: 'fa fa-trash',
            close: 'fa fa-remove'
        }
    }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
        var d = new Date(e.date);
        var day = d.getDate();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = d.getFullYear();
        scope.$apply(function () {
            controller.$setViewValue(day + '-' + month + '-' + year);
        });
    });
}

return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: link
};
});
```

and just "date" is give on text box like this :

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" date class="form-control" name="edu[@{{ $index }}][start_date]"
                                       placeholder="Start Date">
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```